# Issue in WCF with Soap - Automatically request object being manipulated

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, binding

Short Description of Issue  - We had the WCF with REST endpoints (uses basichttpbinding, webhttpbidning &  nettcpbinding)

Now we wanted to provide an Soap related endpoint to newly integrated System hence we added new exposed method  which uses its own service contract and interface with basicHttpBinding .

The service is working fine but in response when we receive - Inside envelope\Header we see couple of  fields available by default even though the target never sends them . For. <ns:To> & <ns:Action> . also, the namespace used in these are different then what we see for the one which are actually sent from Target system .

Tried having messageVersion , textMessageEncoding in binding but these places those are not expected kind of exception we are getting .

[Request data sent from target system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEAYA.jpg)

[Received Request logged at our side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAepS.jpg)

any help would be appreciated .

We changed to custom binding which also not helping at the moment

Comment: NS is namespace.  To parse the xml you need to use the namespace  There is no translation that converts one namespace to another namespace so you must be sending what you are receiving.

Comment: thanks for the respinse @jdweng . I have attached images for the reference too . Traget system not sending those 2 fields , same has been verified with integration systems too . I can confirm the same as even when we test with SOAPUI - its behaving the same way . i.e when it reaches endpoint and in afterreceiverequest  methods i can see those auto added fields clearly . but what exactly enforcing our code to include them in request object is where we are having issues.

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.services.description.soapbinding.namespace?view=netframework-4.8.1

Comment: I once tried adding namespaces after ServiceContract and OperationContract. But when I deleted them, I looked at them in Soapui and found that they always had some namespaces that I didn't add. So I think it's probably coming with the system.